# install windows on a second hardrive (first one on ubuntu)

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I installed a second ssd harddrive on my computer and would like to install windows 10 on it to have a dualboot.

My main harddrive is with ubuntu 14.

I don't want to mess up things here, any one has already done this ?

Comment: I have done it many times.  If you fear messing up your first drive, remove it and install Windows directly to the second one while it is the only drive.

Comment: And then how to I switch from one to another ?

Comment: You would actually boot back to your Ubuntu disk with the Windows drive in and update the GRUB installation (`sudo update-grub`) so the bootloader would see Windows to allow you to boot.  Or, if you are using UEFI, which I am not, you would select the proper boot from the boot menu.

Comment: Ok, I did remove my drive, install windows on new one but when I try to start with both drive plugged, ubuntu does not  boot. I got an error message like "broken ntfs memory blablabla". So right now my dual boot is: unplug first drive, plug second drive which is not ideal .. By the way thanks for helping me

Comment: This was solved booting on windows then deactivating "fast boot option" of Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok that worked for me:

1. unplug linux hard drive
2. plug new hard drive
3. install windows 10
4. go to control pannel of windows 10 and turn off "fast boot option" (really important because ubuntu will think some partition of the hard drive are broken otherwise)
5. replug and boot on linux, update grub

I think step 1 is not mandatory.

Thanks Terrance for the help.